# converting old Managed-C++ Project to new C++/CLI

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, clr, managed-c++

I have this old project written with oldSyntax. It was working just fine in VS2012 but I see that in VS2015 /clr:oldSyntax is no longer available and how I was expecting, I've got a lot of errors.
I managed to get rid of some of them but now I'm blocked on these lines of code:

```
ref class myColumnItemSorterClass : public IComparer
    {
        int IComparer::Compare(Object^ x, Object^ y)
        {
            if (x && y) {
                ColumnItemType^ pSSx = dynamic_cast<ColumnItemType^>(x);
                ColumnItemType^ pSSy = dynamic_cast<ColumnItemType^>(y);

                if (pSSx->Position&&pSSx->Position->Length>0 &&
                    pSSy->Position&&pSSy->Position->Length>0) {

                    int xPos = Convert::ToInt32(pSSx->Position);
                    int yPos = Convert::ToInt32(pSSy->Position);

                    if (xPos < yPos) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (xPos > yPos) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }

            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    };
```

There are 2 errors:

1. at myColumnItemSorterClass -> Class fails to implement interface member function "System::Collections::IComparer::Compare" (declared in "C:...\NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll)
2. at Compare -> Qualified name is not allowed

Any idea how I can fix them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An overridden interface method *must* be `virtual` and `public`, and *may* be `sealed` to prevent a derived class from re-implementing the method.

Do not qualify the method with the interface name (e.g.: `IComparer::Compare`). The compiler will interpret this as a failed attempt to define an explicit override (see compiler error [C3253](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9k716bh.aspx)).

```
ref class myColumnItemSorterClass :  IComparer
{
public:
    virtual int Compare(Object^ x, Object^ y)
    {
        /*...*/
        return 0;
    }
};
```

If you want the overridden method to be accessible only through the interface handle, you can use [explicit overriding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms235235.aspx). The overridden method *must* still be `virtual`, but *can* be `private` and *should* be `sealed`.

```
ref class myColumnItemSorterClass :  IComparer
{
private:
    virtual int CompareExplicit(Object^ x, Object^ y) sealed  = IComparer::Compare
    {
        /*...*/
        return 0;
    }
};
```